# The configuration option 'user instances enabled' does not exist?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 for Window 8

When I built my webpage, sql server suddently stop and show an error :"**Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance. The connection will be closed.** "

Try to fix that problem by searching google. As recommended, I have to delete the folder **C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data**, but there is no folder with that path
Try another way,I run the below code in SQL Query window:

```
exec sp_configure 'user instances enabled', 1.
Go
Reconfigure
```

But it has an error: `The configuration option 'user instances enabled' does not exist, or it may be an advanced option.`

Help!!! Which way is the better one??? And How can I fix this:**Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance. The connection will be closed.**

Comment: the option to enable "Enable User Instances" appears in last steps of SQL Server installation setup, so try un-installing, restarting PC, and then re-install with that option being checked in the setup

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1. Stop all user instance processes of SQL Server running under your local account (open up task manager and look for sqlsrv.exe process and end it)
2. Delete all files in the %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data\SQLEXPRESS folder
   All be aware that if you are using XP the location will be something like
   C:\Documents and Settings\\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data\SQLEXPRESS
3. F5 again

The problem is known issue. SQL Express cannot create a user instance using the set of engine files in your local app data folder, deleting them should allow sql server to recreate them with the correct credentials for you to F5 successfully.

I believe you may not be having SQLExpress installed as directories does not exist. In that case you will need to reinstall the version of SQL Express that was included in the project.